# PHP OAuth on AppFog

Tags: php, oauth, appfog

I'm trying to run a PHP app on AppFog, but I'm seeing this error in the AppFog logs:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Class 'OAuth' not found
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to enable the [OAuth extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth) on AppFog?

Update: afaik now it's not possible to enable specific PHP extensions on AppFog. I've today switched to PagodaBox which allows you to specify additional PHP extensions in the app configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to ask appFog via their support routes or google group. I doubt it though as it's an extension, though depending on if it needs building it might be possible. Is all the source php? If so couldn't you download it, then upload it to your app via 'af update appname' and include the required files?